# Workflow Rule Email Alert

Tags: salesforce

### If a user uses special character in a text fields , then workflow of email alert will run

There are many text fields in student object like Address,firstname,lastname etc. I want to write workflow rule in which if I used any special characters in any of these text fields then automatically an email alert will come

Answer (score 1):

you can try building a formula using contains and mentioning the special characters.

something like -

Also, you would need to define this criteria for all the fields seperately. Something like

fieldname contains !@#$%^&*()_+=-/.,;'[]?><:"{}  || fieldname2 contains !@#$%^&*()_+=-/.,;'[]?><:"{}